# menuToggle CSS Problems - will not display or function

Tags: css, html

Two things:

As of now the menu hides in the top with a top-margin:-100px;and should display below the banner once clicked but it wont know what I seem to try. The menu is in the code/css but can not be displayed, and I am no sure why. I am trying to hide it in the top-margin and have it only display when the user requests it. I hope this helps.

1. Multi color type in my css logo? There has got to be a cleaner way of pulling off that visual. Seems wonky to me.
2. Why wont my menu toggle work? The numbers seem fine? I have been through this code all day, I have no idea and my eyes hurt.

Trying to pull this header off, if I had it my way the nav would simply be in the header, and would display the mobile-icon only for mobile or when the browser window gets collapsed from the side.

I know my code is not very pretty, I am learning and appreciate any help that can be provided.

Thank you, - Phil

http://jsfiddle.net/t6oe93fu/1/

/*------------------CSS Start--------------------*/

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


/*--------PPGD CSS----------*/

<style type="text/css">

body{
    background: #fff;
    margin: 140px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


/*--------HEADER Start----------*/
div#topdiv {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#0F0;
    background:#FFF;
    opacity:0.9;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index:99;
    height:58px;
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(138,136,138,1);
    moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(138,136,138,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(138,136,138,1);
    z-index:99;
}
div#menucontainer {
    height:58px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    display:block;
}

div#container {
    max-width: 942px;
    min-width:320px;
    align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    height:0px;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

/*--------LOGO Start----------*/

div#brand {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:800;
    line-height: 90%;
    color:#F60;
    z-index:99;
}

div#brand1 {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:800;
    line-height: 90%;
    color:#F60;
}

div#brand2 {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:800;
    color:#666; 
    line-height: 90%;
}
div#brand3 {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-left:-161px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:800;
    color:#666; 
    line-height: 90%;
}


/*--------LOGO End----------*/

/*--------MENU Start----------*/

* {padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body { font-family: Open Sans; }
a { text-decoration: none; color:#666; }
li { list-style-type: none; }



nav {
    text-align: center;
    float:right;
    padding: 15px;
    display:block;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    height:19px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing: 0.125em;
    color:#666; 
    line-height: 100%;

}

nav:hover {
    float:right;
    display:block;
    height:19px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing: 0.125em;
    color:#f60; 
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height: 100%;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #f60;
}

nope {
    position:absolute;
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    background: none;
}

div#SAVE{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px #F60;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
    transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
}
}

/*--------MENU End----------*/

/*--------HEADER End----------*/


/*--------FOOTER Start----------*/

div#footer {
    height: 30px;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 5px 0px rgba(138,136,138,1);
    moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 5px 0px rgba(138,136,138,1);
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 5px 0px rgba(138,136,138,1);
    color: #FFF;
}

/*--------FOOTER End----------*/    

    * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body { font-family: 'Open Sans' sans-serif; }
a { text-decoration: none; color: #666; font-size: 14px; }
li { list-style-type: none; }

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 99;
}
.container {
    max-width: 942px;
    min-width:320px;
    align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    height:0px;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
#brnad {
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #F60;
}
nav { width: 100%; text-align: center; }
nav ul { line-height: 50px; }
nav li { display: inline-block; }
nav a { padding: 10px; color: #FFF; }
nav a:hover { background: #F60; color: #FCFCFC; border-radius: 5px; }

/*--------------------------------------------------*/

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-icon {
    float: right;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    color: #666;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99;
}
.menu-icon:hover { color: #F60; }
#menuToggle { display: none; }

#menuToggle:checked ~ .menu { position: absolute; top: 100px; }

.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    nav li { display: block; }
    nav a { display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; padding: 0; }
    nav a:hover { border-radius: 0; }
    .menu { height: auto; top: -350px; }

    #menuToggle:checked ~ .content { position: absolute; top: 370px; }

}


</style>
```

/*------------------CSS End--------------------*/

/*------------------HTML Start--------------------*/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link href="css/PPGD_styles" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/PPGD_styles.css">

<title>Phil Padilla | Portfolio</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="engine1/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



</head>

<body>


  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FF6600">

    <div id="topdiv">
      <div id="container">

<input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle">
<label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</label>
        <div id="brand2">GRAPHIC
          <div id="brand">PHIL</div>
        </div>
        <p><br />
        </p>
     <div id="brand3">DESIGN
        <div id="brand1">PADILLA</div>


        </div>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RESUME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table width="942%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

/*------------------HTML End--------------------*/

Comment: Can you make your question more descriptive please?

Comment: Hi Sleek Geek, I added more information, I hope it helps. This is all very new to me so my apologies if I am not providing the correct information. Thanks! - Phil

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use JS to achieve the menu toggle? Check this fiddle I made a couple of days ago: http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/8cg7bLjL/8/ (You'd need to shrink the screen a little to see the menu toggle show up)

Comment: no, I guess I could just use some JS to achieve the hidden menu. Honestly this is all new to me and I just want it to work no matter the way. Thanks for the link thePav... but I do not get it. I did shrink the screen width and percentage view, did not see it.

Comment: @PhilP, Yep, if you reduce the width of the screen, you'll notice a little link popup: 'Menu', if you click on it, you'll see the menu slide in to view. It was an example for a responsive navigation menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new logo layout example. Just needs a few spans wrapped in a div:

```css
.brand {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #F60;
  line-height: 0.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.name {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.name span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.title {
  margin-left: -54px;
  color: #666;
}
.title span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 118px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand">
  <span class="name">Phil <span>Padilla</span></span>
  <span class="title">Graphic <span>Design</span></span>
</div>
```

It is now capitalized in the CSS, not the HTML. This way when indexed by search engines, it wont look like SHOUTING :)

---

There are many things that could be improved, but the problem in your question is caused by the nav being outside the div the checkbox is in, as it is selected with the sibling selector (`~`).

Unite the siblings, simply place the nav underneath the menu label:

```
<div id="container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle">
      <label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</label>
      <nav class="menu"> </nav>
```

### Working Example

The `top` positioning needs to be changed. I have incorporated the new logo into this example.

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 140px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
/*--------HEADER Start----------*/

div#topdiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #0F0;
  background: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 58px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(138, 136, 138, 1);
  z-index: 99;
}
div#menucontainer {
  height: 58px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
}
div#container {
  max-width: 942px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
/*--------LOGO Start----------*/

.brand {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #F60;
  line-height: 0.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.name {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.name span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.title {
  margin-left: -54px;
  color: #666;
}
.title span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 118px;
}
/*--------LOGO End----------*/

/*--------MENU Start----------*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  height: 19px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 100%;
}
nav:hover {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  height: 19px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.125em;
  color: #f60;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #f60;
}
nope {
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
}
div#SAVE {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px #F60;
  transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
}
}
/*--------MENU End----------*/

/*--------HEADER End----------*/

/*--------FOOTER Start----------*/

div#footer {
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 5px 0px rgba(138, 136, 138, 1);
  color: #FFF;
}
/*--------FOOTER End----------*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans' sans-serif;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
  background: #FFF;
  z-index: 99;
}
.container {
  max-width: 942px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  line-height: 50px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: #F60;
  color: #FCFCFC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-icon {
  float: right;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  color: #666;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99;
}
.menu-icon:hover {
  color: #F60;
}
#menuToggle {
  display: none;
}
#menuToggle:checked ~ .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nav li {
    display: block;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .menu {
    height: auto;
    top: -350px;
  }
  #menuToggle:checked ~ .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="topdiv">
  <div id="container">

    <input type="checkbox" id="menuToggle">
    <label for="menuToggle" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</label>

    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">RESUME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="brand">
      <span class="name">Phil <span>Padilla</span></span>
      <span class="title">Graphic <span>Design</span></span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PhilP - Top of my answer has a simpler logo for you. Just need some spans in a div :)

Comment: you the man misterManSam!!! some of the 'span class' aspects of the logo are not lining up left once back in Dreamweaver, but a much cleaner way of doing what I was going for. I am little confused on how you did it.

Comment: misterManSam - how do I left align the P's in the span class, and also eliminate the space between Padilla and Design? Desired visual is at philpadilla.com, but thats a image.

Comment: @PhilP - I haven't used Dreamweaver in years, but I do remember it not rendering lots of things properly in its internal browser. Just check it in your target browsers and you'll be fine. Basically, the `.name` and `.title` spans are floated next to each other and the spans wrapping the second word in each of them is breaking the word onto a second line :)

Comment: If you want the Ps to line up, then just remove the `margin-left: 10px`. Like [this example here](http://jsbin.com/notiq/1/edit)

Comment: thanks on the text-transform: uppercase; that cracks me up... search engines making my site appear to be SHOUTING!!!! oh thats funny.

Comment: Thank you @misterManSam - double solved indeed. I have way more things I would like to pick your brain about, but it wont let me chat with you because I have a rookie rep.

Comment: @PhilP - You can ask new questions in a new question, of course :) But, make sure the questions are clear and always show your code samples. Also, check that the question hasn't been asked before.